# On the surjectivity of multiplicative maps of sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be any normal projective variety, $\mathcal{L}$ be any line bundle on $X$ and $\mathcal{F}$ be any coherent sheaf on $X$. Then for any non-negative integers $a,b$, we have a multiplicative map
$$ H^0(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes a})\otimes H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes b})\to H^0(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes (a+b)}).$$
If $\mathcal{L}$ is semiample, then by the semiample fibration theorem (Theorem 2.1.26 in Lazarsfeld's positivity in algebraic geometry), there is an algebraic fibre space $\varphi:X\to X_0$, a positive integer $f$ and an ample line bundle $\mathcal{A}$ such that $\varphi^*\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{L}^{\otimes f}$ holds.

Under the above settings, it seems to me that Lazarsfeld assumes that there is a diagram
$$
\begin{aligned}
H^0(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes fa})\otimes H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes fb})&\to H^0(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes (f(a+b))}) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)\\
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\downarrow \alpha& \qquad \qquad \,\,\,\,\,\downarrow\beta\\
H^0(X_0,\varphi_*\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{A}^{\otimes a})\otimes H^0(X_0,\mathcal{A}^{\otimes b})&\to H^0(X_0,\varphi_*\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{A}^{\otimes (a+b)})\,\,\,\,(2)
\end{aligned}
$$
in Example 2.1.28 such that $\alpha,\beta$ are isomorphisms. Certainly, we have two isomorphisms
$$ H^0(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes fa})\otimes H^0(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes fb})\cong H^0(X_0,\varphi_*\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{A}^{\otimes a})\otimes H^0(X_0,\mathcal{A}^{\otimes b})$$
and
$$ H^0(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}^{\otimes f(a+b)})\cong H^0(X_0,\varphi_*\mathcal{F},\mathcal{A}^{\otimes (a+b)})$$
by the projection formula. But I don't know the two isomorphisms makes a commutative diagram as the above. How to get the above commutative diagram? Or, can we prove the statement that if (2) is surjective, then (1) is also surjective without making any commutative diagram as the above?